# Which book of Proakis has dealt with continuous time signals and systems?

Tags: reference-request

I have heard of three books of Proakis namely Communication System Engineering, Digital Signal Processing and Digital Communications. I love the way he writes and would like to read about continuous/analog signals and systems by the same writer. Some of it has been dealt with in his book 'Communication System Engineering' namely Fourier Series and Fourier Transform. I want to read other continuous time topics like Laplace transform by the same author.

> Is there any book by Proakis available which fully deals with
>   continuous time signals and systems?

Answer (score 2):

No, not as far as I know. I can recommend you two books dealing with continuous-time systems, the Fourier transform, and the Laplace transform, among other topics:

1. *Signals and Systems*, Oppenheim, Willsky: a classic, used copies can be found quite cheap
2. *The Fourier Integral and Its Applications*, Papoulis: less scary for an engineer than the title might make you think; it's actually much broader and very accessible; it deals with linear systems in general, low pass and band pass systems, the Laplace transform, etc.